# How to align value axis width?

Tags: amcharts

chart

[image]
I want to align value axis above chart and below chart.
How to set axis width?

Comment: post what you have already tried, where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to go about it is to set [`minMarginLeft`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#minMarginLeft) to the same number on both charts.

I.e.:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chart1", {
  "type": "serial",
  "minMarginLeft": 80,
  // ...
} );

AmCharts.makeChart( "chart2", {
  "type": "serial",
  "minMarginLeft": 80,
  // ...
} );
```

Comment: Thanks! This also solved the sync cursor problem when two graphics has different widths.